# A simple text file wouldn't be created [C, GCC]

Tags: c, file, ubuntu, gcc

Below is a simple code that I'm hoping `SIZE.txt` to be created, then be closed. It compiles without error, nor warning, but file wouldn't be created. However, a segmentation fault is thrown when code is executed.

Thanks for your kind help in advance.

```
#include "stdio.h"

void main() {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("SIZE.txt", "r+");
    fclose(fp);
    return;
}
```

Comment: You must check the result `fp != NULL` before trying to close it. The file probably does not exist on the path you think it is on.

Comment: The man page says *"r+" Opens for both reading and writing. The file must exist.* So when you say the file could not be created: no, it could not.

Comment: My suggestion would be `man fopen`

Comment: `fopen("SIZE.txt", "w");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary reason for the failure was due to the specification of the file *mode* as `"r+"` which will only open *existing files*, not *create new files*. A file is only created if `"w+", "a"`, or `"a+"` is specified as the file *mode*.

check this, if file exists it will be display file already exist, but if the file doesn't exist it will be create it, depend what are you going to do, the ab+ you can just change to w

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("SIZE.txt", "r");
if(fp==NULL){
    fp=fopen("SIZE.txt", "ab+");
    printf("File was created\n");
}
else{
    printf("File already exists\n");
}
fclose(fp);
return 0;
```

Comment: You may want to incorporate (and explain) the primary reason for the failure, the specification of the *mode* as `"r+"` which will only open *existing* files, not *create* new files. A file is only created if `"w+"`, `"a"`, or `"a+"` is specified as the mode -- then your answer would warrant an upvote. Welcome to S.O.

Comment: Yes, you right i should specify what i wrote, next time i will not commit this error, i am new in stack and thanks for the notice/attention

Comment: Ok then, I'll keep my end -- on the goal that you are free to plagiarizer my comment to add the explanation to your answer to it will be a fine, teaching example on the subject and worthy of an upvote.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all ;) and sorry for my non-perfect english

Comment: Thank you both for the help. I couldn't realize that ´opening´ a file and  ´creating´ a file are different things. Though I trust in my English skills, it sometimes fails me badly.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
#include "stdio.h"
```

To

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Also, check for a NULL pointer being returned by fopen():

```
if ((fp = fopen("file.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
   // Handle error...
}
```

Comment: Changed `"stdio.h"` to `<stdio.h>`. It returns `NULL`, and `SIZE.txt` still remains missing.

Comment: Is the path to SIZE.txt correct?

Comment: @MetinOktayYılmaz yes the file remains missing, and you lack the ability to read comments, let alone man pages. So get on with it, or do you need a link FFS?

Comment: Expected t be created? you're trying to open it for reading...it should have been created before you call fopen()...

Comment: How many times do you need to be told that the mode "r+" will not create a file?

Comment: He's trying to help you? why ask for help then give attitude when people oblige?

Comment: @Weather Vane Thanks for the help.

Comment: Oh my god I won't be able to sleep for I have embarrased myself so badly...

Comment: You trying to tell us you're fully awake?